# Mono application on FreeBSD: Correct location for dynamic plugins?

Tags: c#, mono, freebsd

I'm developing an application for FreeBSD that is written in C# and will be run via Mono. I would like to include assemblies that are loaded at runtime as plugins, but I'm not sure what the appropriate filesystem layout would be that would follow the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/dirstructure.html).

The application will run as a daemon as the root user, so the directory where plugins are kept should probably not be writable except by root, I would think. Is it acceptable to create subdirectories under `/usr/local/sbin/` ?

Answer (score 0):

For example, apps developed using [Mono.Addin](https://github.com/mono/mono-addins)s library often search the directories below:

```
/usr/lib/MyApplication
[ApplicationData]/MyApplication/addins
```

As described at [Addin Discovery Basics](https://github.com/mono/mono-addins/wiki/Addin-Discovery-Basics).